# MVC Model not passed to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

Am almost embarassed that I can't get this to work. I have a model like this:

```
public class Test
{
  public string Test1 {get; set; }
  public string Test2 {get; set; }
}
```

I have a razor view which correctly displays both Test1 and Test2. Test1 is displayed just like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => mode.Test1)
@Html.Test1
```

Test2 is displayed like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test2)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test2)
```

i.e. I just want to display Test1, but want the user to be able to edit Test2.

These are within a form:

```
@using(Hmtl.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post)
```

In Controller1.Action1 it receives the model:

```
public ActionResult Action1(Test m)
{

}
```

but in here m.Test1 is null, m.Test2 is correctly populated. m.test1 is correctly displayed in the view.

Am confused.com

Thanks in advance,

Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binder only sees the form values which are posted from the HTML form, which are only from form elements.  This doesn't generate such an element:

```
@Html.Test1
```

That may display the value to which the view is bound (does it really?  I've never seen it done like that, maybe that should be `@Model.Test1`?) but there needs to be an HTML form element of some kind to post a value back to the server.  (`input`, `select`, `hidden`, etc.)

For fun, take a look at the HTML generated in the browser.  They're just standard form elements with values, there's nothing storing the whole model anywhere.  The model binder just tries to intelligently re-construct a model based on the name/value pairs sent from the HTML form.

Try adding a hidden field to the form as well:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test1)
@Model.Test1
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Test1)
```

This should create an `input type="hidden"` in the form with that value, which would be included when posting the values to the controller action.

Comment: Got it. Yes it should be @model.Test1 - typo. So how would you do it with a nested object? Thanks.

Comment: @RBrowning99: That makes it a little more complicated, but the general principle is still the same.  When you generate a field with something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NestedObject.Field1)` take a look at the `input` that it generates.  The key to re-assembling the model in the binding is the `name` attribute of the form elements, those are what the model binder uses to map the value to the expected model type.

Comment: Yeh got it - doesn't really work, does it? I wanted to send it an object, and have the object come back to me. I think I'll send it the object, and just have the PK and the timestamp of the object come back and reassemble the object in the controller if I need to.

Comment: @RBrowning99: Well, you can't put an *entire* object in a single field.  In the HTML the field's value is just text.  (Though, you probably could serialize an entire object into a single field, accept a string input on the action method, and de-serialize it back to an object.)  You either need to put enough data elements on the page to completely re-assemble the object, or put at least an identifier so you can re-acquire the object based on that identifier.