# Object model not passed to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am in a very strange situation.

My object model is not passed to my controller and I don't understand why, really. I will attach the code, maybe there is a typo that causes the bug.

Code:

Model:

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    [Display(Name ="Title")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Title must have at least 5 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Link is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Link")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Link must have at least 5 characters")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Source")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Source must have at least 3 characters")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is read")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Notes field must have at least 5 characters")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model CarrerTrack.Web.Model.Article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Link)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Link)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Source)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Source)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsRead)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsRead)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notes)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserId)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> 
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller(part of it):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Model.Article article)
{
    var _article = _articleReadApp.GetById(article.ArticleId);
    _articleCommandApp.Remove(_article.ArticleId);
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Article");
}
```

Please note that Edit (Post wo[image]rks), delete (Post) does not.

I have some experience with ASP.NET MVC. This one surpass me, I need your help. It seems easy, but I cannot find the solution although this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488066/mvc-model-not-passed-to-controller) and there are plenty tutorials on the web. I deleted the View delete and created another one. Still no success. Any help?

Comment: You don't have any form controls inside the `<form>` element.  What method do you want to post to - the `Delete()` method? In which case you pass back just the value of the `ArticleId ` property (not the whole model) which you can do as a route parameter

Comment: The controller's code in the image is different that then code in your posted code.

Comment: And you model is `Article` yet all you methods refer to `JobAnnouncement`!

Comment: I put the correct controller having only the Delete problem. The issue seemed to be on the view. It is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data inside hidden fields. Your view should be like this:

```
@model CarrerTrack.Web.Model.Article

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";   }

 <br />

 <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
 <div>
   <hr />
   <dl class="dl-horizontal">
       <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Link)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Link)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Source)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Source)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsRead)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsRead)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notes)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserId)
    </dd>

</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Link)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Source)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsRead)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Notes)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ArticleId)
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> 
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn       btn-default" })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP should pass `Notes` and `IsRead` and other properties if they just want to delete an article? And what you are suggesting is basically doubling the size of the data when the page is requested.

Comment: Passing all those unnecessary values is not only pointless (only the ID is required to delete an item), its degrading performance

Comment: I agree that only ArticleId is enough for deleting an article. But in case SO answer, it will give author better understanding how it works

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, and thank you Guys for the comments. Indeed I only need the id. But, if I would like to delete articles having, let;s say the same source, then I will have to keep @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Source) .

Answer (score 1):

Only inputs of form are sent back and can be passed to model object by binders.

If you change your `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.XXX)` to `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.XXX)` and put everything inside of `@using (Html.BeginForm())`
 it should work. You can make inputs readonly\disabled to mimic `DisplayFor` behavior.

Comment: Why do you think the OP, or anyone, would need to show an editor to delete something. I think its perfectly ok to show labels with a delete button to be able to delete something. You just need to pass the id of the item you want to delete.

Comment: It will work, but if he doesn't want to show inputs, he need to pass params with hidden fields.

Comment: Sure, he just needs ID of the item. But the question was about the reasons why model is empty. So my answer explains this.